# how to add an ADD AS A FRIEND button on a listview generated by json object

Tags: android, listview

Hi im having a list of people who were derived from a json object and put in to a listview as bellow. i want to put an add button infront of the name, rather making an onslect and moving it to a new activity.

how can i do that?

following is how i genarate my data in to the listview. i can add a button from the xml where i define the row. but how to put or rather how to code the button.onclick?

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> friendslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            if (jArray != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    a = json_data.getString("user_id");

                    map.put(TAG_Name, json_data.getString("fname"));
                    map.put(TAG_LName, json_data.getString("lname"));
                    friendslist.add(map);
                }
            }
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addfrndslist);

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, friendslist,
                    R.layout.add_yourfriendswith, new String[] { TAG_Name,
                            TAG_LName}, new int[] { R.id.afname,
                            R.id.alname});
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: How does a Button get generated from a JSON Object ?

Comment: i can add a button to the row and by clicking that i can get it added. but do not know how to and where to code Button.onclick method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create Custom List Adapter to add Button to your list rows.

Write this in

```
final ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);

itemlist.setAdapter(new PodcastListAdapter(this));
```

And then create custom BaseAdapter Class

```
class ViewHolder {
TextView txtTitle;
TextView txtDescription;
Button btnDownload;
}

public class PodcastListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;

public PodcastListAdapter(Context cont) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(cont);
    context = cont;
}

public int getCount() {
    return Utilities.arrayRSS.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return Utilities.arrayRSS.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.btnDownload = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);

        holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DownloadingProgressTask(position, holder).execute();
                holder.btnDownload
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.downloading);
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtTitle.setText(Utilities.arrayRSS.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(Utilities.arrayRSS.get(position)
            .getDescription());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: thnx that is after my list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addfrndslist);

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, friendslist,
                    R.layout.add_yourfriendswith, new String[] { TAG_Name,
                            TAG_LName}, new int[] { R.id.afname,
                            R.id.alname});
            list.setAdapter(adapter); right?

Comment: No above lines you don't have to write, please search for how to create custom Listview in android.

Answer (score 0):

For your list view you are using SimpleAdapter provided by android but this works only when you have to display a list of names. If you want your list to be customized according to your need like adding buttons or images etc on each of the row then you will have to make your own adapter.

Here are the steps to do this:

1. Write your custom adapter by extending BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter
2. Override its methods.

> Note: If you add any clickable item to the list view row then the item will be clickable but list will not be clickable. And hence the list onItemClickListener will not work. Now in this case for getting the position of the item clicked you have to do some workaround. I use setTag() on the row items and getTag() method to get the tag which will be the it's position in the group.

Here is a sample code for this:
 **XML for the row item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add"
            android:onClick="addFriend"
        />  
</LinearLayout>
```

**Code for custom Adapter**

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    String names[];
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyListAdapter(String _names[],Context context) {
        names = _names;
        mInfalter = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount ( )
    {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem (int position)
    {
        return names[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId (int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInfalter.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder.name = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.addBrn = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.templeName.setText(names[position]);
        holder.addBtn.setTag(Integer.toString(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        Button addBtn;
    }

}
```

Here is the method called when the add button is clicked

```
public void addFriend(View v) {
    int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
    //now you have the position of the button that you can use for your purpose
}
```

Here is the code for setting the adapter

```
//String array of names
 String[] names;

 MyListAdapter mAdapter = new MyListAdapter(names,yourActivity.this);
 list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

> I hope this will help :)

Comment: It will be of immense help if you give proper reason before unaccepting an answer so, that I can improve my answer.